# Changing Sequences index

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, odbc

I want to create new menuitem: Contact with sequence value: 3.

How do i change menuitem History to sequence 4 and Information to sequence 5 when adding menuitem contact??

i use PHP with Sql Server 2008 (with an ODBC Connection).

Table = MenuItems

Rows: Sequence::Menuitem

1::Home
2::Photo
3::History
4::Information

**After creating menuitem: Contact**
1::Home
2::Photo
3::Contact
4::History
5::Information

Answer (score 0):

Update the table items after insert:

```
UPDATE MenuItems SET Sequence = Sequence + 1 WHERE Sequence >= 3 AND MenuItem != 'Contact'
```

This adds 1 to every sequence number to the menus after Contact.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know where the new item landed:

```
update MenuItems
  set Sequence += 1
  where Sequence >= @NewItemSequence and Id <> @NewItemId
```